Is it possible to create single-use queues in RabbitMQ?
I want to create a unique queue for each REST call received to the micro-service for it to communicate with another microservice. Is it possible to create single-use queues to communicate between two microservices?
I am new to RabbitMQ. I want to create two spring-boot microservices which communicate through RabbitMQ queues. As microservice1 receives a REST call for its endpoint it should send a message to microservice2 and receive a response message and send it back to user. Here microservice1 should create a queue for every request so that microservice2 can listen for that queue provide the response and then the queue should get deleted.  I want this lifecycle to be synchronous.

How is that better than using the same queue over and over?

Right.  Why not a single queue with an identifier?

@TimRoberts  When I used a single queue, issues occurred when I attempted to send multiple requests simultaneously. I introduced a 5-second thread sleep on the server side of the message queue, but when consuming through just one queue, all the requests were delayed until the first request was completed. Which made most of the replies become timed out

@500-InternalServerError Since I'm using request-reply pattern single queue could not handle multiple requests at once when there a delay in the server end of the queue.

Maybe what you want is an sendAndReceive or convertSendAndReceive like "RPC".
rabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(RabbitMQConstants.EXCHANGE_NAME,
                            routingKey,
                            message,
                            getMessagePostProcessor(),
                            new CorrelationData(UUID.randomUUID().toString())));



private static MessagePostProcessor getMessagePostProcessor() {
        return messagePostProcessor -> {
            messagePostProcessor.getMessageProperties().setHeader("offSetDateTime", OffsetDateTime.now());
            messagePostProcessor.getMessageProperties().setMessageId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            messagePostProcessor.getMessageProperties().setTimestamp(Date.from(OffsetDateTime.now().toInstant()));
            messagePostProcessor.getMessageProperties().setReplyTo(RabbitMQConstants.EXCHANGE_NAME.concat("_reply-to"));
            messagePostProcessor.getMessageProperties().setDelayLong(5L);

            return messagePostProcessor;
        };
    }

See this:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/amqp/request-reply.html
